# Is it normal that the co-authors can't see my camera-ready submission in CPS?

Tags: paper-submission, conference, online-publication, ieee

I submitted the camera-ready manuscript via the IEEE CPS online system, and I have a "Previous Submissions to the Conference" section in my page. But the other co-authors, who also recieved the email about submitting camere-ready manucript, cannot see the submission record via the link in the email (log in by their own account). Is this normal? Or is there anything going wrong?

Comment: I think the only people who can help you are the ones running the conference. Nobody here has access to your specific account to help you with this question.

Comment: I have sent emails to the CPS and they havn't replied. Actually I think it is very likely to be just the nature of the CPS online system, so I wonder if there is anyone who used the CPS online and had the similar experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IEEE Conference Publishing Services](https://www.computer.org/conferences/cps) isn't like a normal submission and review system: it's more akin to the proofing and copyright form systems of other publishers.

As such, my experience with it has always been that:

1. it's kind of weird and bespoke,
2. the conference organizers aren't really involved, once they give the list of accepted papers to IEEE, so things often go a bit wrong during the hand-off, and
3. the system is mostly intended for just one designated author to interact with it just once.

Your experience thus sounds pretty normal to me. As long as you (or at least somebody) can upload the camera-ready manuscript, it should all be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have asked the CPS and they confirmed only the author who submitted can see the submission status.